# Delete from huge MySQL table if data exists in another table

Tags: mysql

I know this one's been asked before but this one has a twist.
I got an email table (table 1) of around 1.5M records.

I got to check it against another table (table2) which has around 80K records and I need to delete from table1 where email addresses match with table1.

I tried delete from table1 where email in (select email from table2) but MySQL throws an error.
Error Code : 1205
Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
(50404 ms taken)

I could not do in PHP because I have around 5 more tables like table2 which I need to filter from table1.

I would like to do this in MySQL as that is our safest route but I want a query that could run in minutes (under an hour) and give results.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Got 1 day left to deliver. :-)

Comment: Did you try using LIMIT at the end of your query? You'd have to run it a few times, but it shouldn't time out then.

Comment: I tried limit but even with limit, it was taking around 1 second per record deleted. e.g. this query DELETE FROM table1 WHERE
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.email = table2.email)
LIMIT 100

Comment: You got any foreign keys with cascading deletes ? Please show indexes and EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way. `IN` clause could be very slow.

```
delete table1.*
from table1
left join table2
on table1.email = table2.mail
where table2.mail is not null
```

Comment: why not inner join without the where?

Comment: Nice question. :) I've always used left join for this kind of query but I wait other opinions. I have to test performance differences.

Comment: Try to add an index on table1 on email field.

Comment: This one worked.
`code DELETE FROM table1 WHERE
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.email = table1.email)
LIMIT 100` but can I use limit INSIDE the subquery somehow. There's gotta be a way around this, right?

Comment: Is there maybe a way where we can do these in Cursors?

Answer (score 0):

You could higher the wait timeout value in your my.cnf:

```
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 250
```

Comment: Sure, but if everything else fails it could help.

Comment: also running locally yet on wamp and my.ini has this line commented.

Answer (score 0):

Updating this answer because I finally did it.

1. I dropped the fulltext index on emails and made a new 100 character index on email.
2. I think used simple IN query to match the tables
3. The whole process took like seconds rather than minutes/hours.

Thank you for all your help. I am indebted all the same.

Much regards